# I want to create a new column and use cast function for typecasting on it in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to create a new column that has data in the `DateTime` format but want only the time data from it, I tried the following function in `BigQuery`

```
SELECT *,
(start-end) as ride_length
cast(ride_length as time)
FROM xyz
```

It won't run it shows the error `ride_length` is an unknown name. please someone provide a solution with an explanation. Thank you.

Comment: `select *,
(start-end) as ride_length
cast((start-end)) as time
from xyz`

Comment: You're missing a comma (,) after **ride_length** and also you can't refer **ride_length**  alias in select list directly.

Comment: One of workaroud in this case is **SELECT *, cast(ride_length as time) FROM xyz, UNNEST([start-end]) ride_length**